# .NET Framework : how to disable lazy loading in EF6 with code first convention?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0

Please explain, how to disable the lazy loading option in EF6 with the code-first convention? Note that I already tried to disable it in the `DbContext` for all entities that are using virtual navigation property's.

Also note that I generated the database using the Code First  approach and I have the lazy loading option set to `false` with also proxy creation to `false` as well.

My `DbContext` config

```
{
    public MyContext():base("name=MaChaine")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Account> accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<deposit> deposits { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Withdraw> withdraws { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<import_history> import_Histories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<POS>  points_of_sales { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ticket> tickets { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //config + customconventions
        // one to many : Point of sales can have many accounts but an account can have one only point of sale 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasRequired<POS>(a => a.POS)
            .WithMany(p => p.accounts)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(a => a.id_pos)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        // one to many : an account can have many tickets but ticket can have one only account
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>()
            .HasRequired<Account>(t2 => t2.Account)
            .WithMany(a2 => a2.Tickets)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(t2 => t2.n_acccount)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        // one to many : an account can have many deposit transactions but deposit are for one only account 
        modelBuilder.Entity<deposit>()
            .HasRequired<Account>(d => d.Account)
            .WithMany(a3 => a3.deposits)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(d => d.Id_Account)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        // one to many ; account can have many withdraws but a withdraw can only be for one account
        modelBuilder.Entity<Withdraw>()
            .HasRequired<Account>(w => w.Account)
            .WithMany(a4 => a4.Withdraws)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(w => w.N_account)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

POS class :

```
public class POS
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code_pos { get; set; }
    public string r_social { get; set; }
    public string nom_commercial { get; set; }
    public int n_tva { get; set; }
    public string t_pos { get; set; }
    public string mode_op { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public string prenom { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string exploitant { get; set; }
    public string depends_on { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_creation { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_change_status { get; set; }
    public string type_contract { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Account> accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Account class:

```
public class Account
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int n_account { get; set; }
    public string pseudo { get; set; }
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public string prenom { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_birth { get; set; }
    public int cin { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string statut { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_creation { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int id_pos { get; set; }
    public POS POS { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<deposit> deposits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Withdraw> Withdraws { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }     
}
```

This is what I received as a result I want to remove the `null` account for the POS

```
[{
    "ID": 1,
    "Code_pos": "dfd",
    "r_social": "testpos",
    "nom_commercial": "testpos",
    "n_tva": 2,
    "t_pos": "testpos",
    "mode_op": "testpos",
    "nom": "testpos",
    "prenom": "testpos",
    "phone": "testpos",
    "email": "testpos",
    "exploitant": "testpos",
    "depends_on": "testpos",
    "status": "testpos",
    "date_creation": "1990-02-02T00:00:00",
    "date_change_status": "1990-02-02T00:00:00",
    "type_contract": "type",
    "accounts": null
}]
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with lazy loading.  If you want `accounts` removed from the JSON, you modify your JSON serializer, eg https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm

Comment: Hello @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , 

First thank you for your answer, i''m checking this " sorry i tought it was null because i didn't fill the accounts table that's why i said lazy loading" any way i hae a question , the account is vritual a navigation property why it get serialzed in first place ? , thank oyu again for your answer

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thank you for opening my eyes i was able to find out the issue it's true as you said it's not lazy loading ' i only thought that because i only populated the pos class, any way it was Json serializing issue so it was fixed by adding the the below line in the webapiconfig in appstart 
"             config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true; "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed, it's not lazy loading but Json serializing issue that display the navigations property's, it was fxied by adding the below code in the Webapiconfig for the API project

```
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
```

Thanks to @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Source to fix issue is also below :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization